# Multiple joins in multiple tables

Tags: sql, inner-join, multiple-tables

i have the tables below:

```
patient: id, incidentCode, name, insurance, contactdetailsID
contactDetails: id, cityCode
lookup: id, lookupdescription
incident: id, date
```

patient joins contactdetails like:

```
inner join contactdetails on patient.contactdetailsid=contactdetails.id
```

patient joins incident like:

```
inner join incident on patient.incidentCode=incident.id
```

patient joins lookup like:

```
inner join lookup on patient.insurance = lookup.id
```

and contact details joins lookup like:

```
inner join lookup on contactdetails.citycode = lookup.id
```

and now i want to Select both Lookup.lookupDescription from patient insurance and contactdetails Citycode.
How can i do that? At select i also want patient.name, patient.id, incident.date

Comment: Have you tried something? Post yout query

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
SELECT
  patient.id,
  lookup.lookupdescription,
  contactDetails.cityCode
FROM patient
INNER JOIN contactdetails on patient.contactdetailsid=contactdetails.id
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE patient.id = xy
```

By the way: The last `JOIN` you provide doesn't look that meaningful to me?! It looks like `lookup.id` is an citycode and at the same time is an insurance number?!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  d.lookupDescription,
        a.insurance,
        e.Citycode,
        a.name,
        a.id,
        c.date
FROM    patient a
        INNER JOIN contactdetails b
            ON a.contactdetailsid = b.id
        INNER JOIN  incident c
            ON a.incidentCode = c.id
        INNER JOIN lookup d
            ON a.insurance = d.id
        INNER JOIN contactdetails e
            ON e.citycode = d.id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)